# lua curses example using luaposix

Tags: lua, posix, openwrt, curses, ash

As I understood curses are integrated into the luaposix project.
Since I am using a OpenWRT which is very limited linux environment,and it runs ash for shell, I would like to develop some curses text-based menus, or better to say a textbased  user interface that runs on OpenWRT.

I have found that luaposix 35.1.1 is available as an opkg (already compiled) for the OpenWRT device.
The OpenWRT system does run LUA v5.1.5.

My questions is where can I found a curses example that utilizes luaposix for making a simple text based menu?
I have googled and found nothing to start with.

In order to learn and code the curses finding a relevant tutorial or a guide is really handy.

Please note I do not want to use other libraries, or solutions other than luaposix.

Answer (score 0):

> As I understood curses are integrated into the luaposix project.

lcurses is not integrated into luaposix anymore:

> For a while, luaposix contained support for curses functionality too, but now it has its own [lcurses](https://github.com/lcurses/lcurses) repository again, where it is being maintained separately.
>
> - https://github.com/luaposix/luaposix

An [example](http://lcurses.github.io/lcurses/examples/curses.lua.html) is given on the [documentation site](http://lcurses.github.io/lcurses/examples/curses.lua.html).